# Getting error in heat map using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, argentina

I need to make a color map, but I'm not allowed to do it because in the "radio" field I get a warning that says:

> Distance is in geographic degrees, consider reprojecting a local
>   coordinate system projected to get accurate results.

I would need to know what kind of projection I should do to be able to make my heat map. I am from Argentina.

Comment: Esto es un sitio web en inglés. No es aceptable escribir en español. Por favor, traduzca su pregunta a inglés.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please avoid the use of ALL UPPERCASE titles here, since this is widely regarded as SHOUTING, and is downvoted.

Comment: Si usted habla a Inglés, puede utilizar los servicios como https://tradukka.com/translate para traducir tu pregunta. -- If you dont speak English, you can use services like https://tradukka.com/translate to translate your question.

Answer (score 3):

I am from Argentina too but I will answer you in English, because that is the way that we can understand each other with the greatest number of people from all countries.

In accordance with the [Disposición 20/2009](http://ramsac.ign.gob.ar/posgar07_pg_web/documentos/Disposicion_Marco_POSGAR_07.pdf)  of the former *Instituto Geográfico Militar*, the geodetic reference framework for Argentina is POSGAR 07.

The official cartography is divided into meridian strips (*fajas*). According to your work area you must choose the corresponding strip and project to that coordinate system.

You must export your layers, and save them as new layers in those systems. 
The corresponding EPSG codes are from the **EPSG:5343** for *Faja 1* to **EPSG:5349** for *Faja 7*.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a UTM projection, such as `EPSG:32721` - `WGS 84 / UTM zone 21S`.
UTM is a metric projection, so your units will be meters.

However, the "best" CRS depends on where your data is exactly located at.
Here is a list of projected CRS for Argentina: https://epsg.io/?q=Argentina%20kind%3APROJCRS

You may also want to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system to get a general overview. Don't miss the subsequent links at this wiki site.

To reproject your layer `right click` it and choose `Export` --> `Save Features As`

[image]

Now click on `select CRS` and search for the one you want to have. Select it and press OK. Now save it as a new file. - Done.

[image]